# IE With on .change() form submit()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code :

```
$('#button').click(function () {
    $('#file').click();
});
$('#file').change(function (){
    $('#form').submit();
});


 <form style="display:none;" id="form" method="post" target="upload_target" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload">

 <input id="file" name="file" id="file" type="file" /><br />        
  <input type="submit" name="action" value="Upload Image" /><br />      
  <iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="" style="width:100;height:100;border:00;"></iframe>   

</form>

  <span id="button" class="button def">upload</span>
```

Where is problem?
This works on Firefox, Chrome but not on IE

Comment: It would save you a lot of confusion in the future if you didn't create elements with the same `id` as the actual element. (In other words, don't call your `<form>` with `id="form"`, but instead call it something as simple as `id="form1"`

Comment: I wasn't suggesting it as a solution to this particular issue, just something to stop confusion in the future.  If you have already written code for those particular `id` values, then it's possible you could starting missing them when updating your code, so be careful not to break it even further!

Comment: thx for suggest , these codes [ id, names or other attrs ] are just for example...

Answer (score 3):

Check out your selector, Remove that # from the selector from the second part like this.

```
$('input[type=file]').change(function(){
    $('#form').submit();
});
```

This should work perfectly.

Comment: sry, ill edit my question , thats not my problem ! the code works fine on other browsers ,but in IE not working...

Comment: In that case make sure your form id is `form`

Comment: Clear your cache on IE and check. Make sure your form is wrapping correctly all the elements. Otherwise I do not find any problem with the code.

Comment: oh , for testing , i make an " alert('test'); " before $("#form").submit(); . alert works,! but the form is not submited, [ Cache is cleared].

Comment: Ok then try the normal javascript method like this instead of jQuery `document.getElementById("form").submit();` and try.

Comment: still not working , i think when form is submitted nothing from #file sending to server-side !!

Answer (score 1):

`$('input[type=file]')` it should be `input` only if you want to select by tagName , you should use `#` before the selector if you want to select element by ID

**Edit:**

if you checked the console you will see that you have this error on IE `SCRIPT5: Access is denied.`  this because of security rules of IE

> you can't access an Iframe  in a page with different domain names .

after some search I found something that may help you , You have to set the document.domain to the same thing on both the parent page and its iframe, in order for them to talk to each other.

```
document.domain = "yourdomain.com"
```

source : http://www.tomhoppe.com/index.php/2008/03/cross-sub-domain-javascript-ajax-iframe-etc/

Good luck.

Comment: which event not firing , click or change ?

Comment: @saeidnc your code is working ok , on IE10 , could u tell me ur IE version , and please post your html too

Comment: see question , posted my html too , IE9

Comment: so what i have to do? :-??

Comment: @Saeid try to set the domain in the page and the iframe

Comment: Why!!!!! Still not working ! iFrame src:ex.com/user/media/photos,page url : ex.com/user/media/photos

Answer (score 0):

Internet explorer does not allow uploading file that was triggered via Javascript. What you are doing, which is triggering the click function of the file browser via a button and then trying to send whatever file that is selected would not work in IE. You would get Access Denied error.

It is not a bug in your code, it is just a restriction in how IE works.